# How can I count form fields with the same id?

Tags: javascript

What I want should be very simple I think, but I end up with too complex situations if I search here, or on Google.

```
<script language="javascript">

// putten tellen

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='number']").keyup(function () {
        $.fn.myFunction();
    });
    $.fn.myFunction = function () {
        var minute_value = $("#minute").val();
        var second_value = $("#second").val();

        if ((minute_value != '')) {
            var productiesec_value = (1 / (parseInt(minute_value) * 60 + parseInt(second_value)));
            var productiemin_value = productiesec_value * 60;
            var productieuur_value = productiesec_value * 3600;
            var productiedag_value = productiesec_value * 86400;
            var productieweek_value = productiesec_value * 604800;
            var productiemaand_value = productiesec_value * 2629700;
            var productiejaar_value = productiesec_value * 31556952;


            productiesec_value = (productiesec_value).toFixed(5);
            productiemin_value = (productiemin_value).toFixed(2);
            productieuur_value = (productieuur_value).toFixed(2);
            productiedag_value = (productiedag_value).toFixed(0);
            productieweek_value = (productieweek_value).toFixed(0);
            productiemaand_value = (productiemaand_value).toFixed(0);
            productiejaar_value = (productiejaar_value).toFixed(0);

            $("#productiesec").val(productiesec_value.toString());
            $("#productiemin").val(productiemin_value.toString());
            $("#productieuur").val(productieuur_value.toString());
            $("#productiedag").val(productiedag_value.toString());
            $("#productieweek").val(productieweek_value.toString());
            $("#productiemaand").val(productiemaand_value.toString());
            $("#productiejaar").val(productiejaar_value.toString());
        }
    };
});

</script>
```

The thing I'd like to accomplish is:

- Calculate the production time of a gem in multi-types of time (seconds, minutes, hours etc.) - (Done)
- Calculate the production of gems by multiple pits.

Preview: http://hielke.net/projecten/productie/edelsteenput.htm

The idea is that you fill in the minutes in the first field and the seconds in the second field. Then the script should count the production in seconds, minutes, hours etc. on the right side.

After that it must be possible to fill in the second row of minutes and seconds and then counts the total production time. The same for the rest of the rows.

Comment: First lesson: you can't have multiple elements on a page with the same "id" value. They have to be unique; that's why it's called an "id".

Comment: Why does O in noob have to be capitalized? Captain?

Comment: As an addenda, your being a "noob" (or however you wish to capitalise it) is entirely irrelevant to the problem itself.

Comment: Captain here: @AmitJoki originally, back in the days, it was written `n00b`  with a zero `0`. You could also be `l337` which meant *elite*. *Pointy* and *David Thomas* qualify for the latter. It's called [`leetspeak`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet). *flies away*.

Comment: \*flies away\* @Mouser

Comment: @AmitJoki how are you displaying * without making it italic?

Comment: @Mouser escaping with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

A caveat about your setup: **whenever possible, avoid having elements share IDs on your page**. IDs are generally for elements which only occur once on your page; otherwise use a class. This practice is why `document.getElementById()` returns a single element, while `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, which makes the answer to your question as easy as getting that array's `.length`.

This being said -- counting the number of elements with the same ID in Javascript is generally considered invalid, as `getElementById()` will only return one element, and (as far as I know) there isn't a way to iterate over instances of the same ID on a page.

Try changing those IDs to class names if you can, the run a `document.getElementsByClassName().length` on them to get the count.

Comment: Or in jQuery `$(".[replace with shared classname]")` or plain (alternative): `document.querySelectorAll(".[replace with shared classname]")`